# Change language to English on Honor 5C

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Please guide me. I cannot read Chinese. How do I go about changing the language to English. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

设置 (Settings) - 语言与输入法 (Language & input) - 语言 (Language) - English (United States) (or any language you're looking for).